# Meta background flickers on some monitors

Tags: bug, design

On my Dell S2309W (but not my Dell 2009W), the Arqade Meta background flickers.  If I zoom in to 150% or more (I'm guessing that turns the 1-pixel rows into 2-pixel rows), the flicker is eliminated.

I don't know much about LCDs, I've heard about "[pixel walk](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/inversion.php)" but I don't know if this is that, but tweaking the non-black pixel (45, 45, 45) to something with a hint of color (50, 50, 45) seems to abolish it.  A slightly different grey (50, 50, 50) still gives me flicker.

Example (run in JS console <kbd>F12</kbd>...):

```
document.body.style.background="transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/n0wE8VJ.png) top center";
```

Revert:

```
document.body.style.background="transparent url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamingmeta/img/bg-body.png?v=42) top center";
```

Slightly related, probably because of my monitor freaking out about 1 px grey/black patterns, I'm also able to easily see the difference between "bg-header.png" and "bg-body.png".  The "header" background grey (used in the footer) is 1-bit brighter: (46, 46, 46).

Comment: Mine only flickers as I scroll to the top.  It's kind of like a bounce effect when trying to scroll past the top.  When it's static, I don't see any flicker.  (Macbook Air 11 inch screen)

Comment: Does the whole background flicker or just the footer?  Might just be [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/flickering-side-bars-on-meta?rq=1), which was only half-fixed.

Comment: Everywhere that is dark grey.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on the main area on my system, but I can repro with the footer at least.

Comment: Actually, I can add that I'm seeing a VERY faint flicker in the background when stationary, but this seems to be more of a moire pattern than a flicker.

Comment: it flickers on my laptop but not my desktop

Comment: I'm not seeing any flickering either.

Comment: I can't repro the flickering both on my 27" iMac and PC monitor.

Comment: @Jin myself, z and David (not sure how he would get a moire) can repro it.  It seems like a trivial fix along with the other thing for something that's exceedingly obnoxious on a wider monitor.

Comment: Hey @NickT - do you still see this problem with the new site design? (The background only really exists on the header and footer now).