# Pixel seam visible in meta background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

While I'm bringing up [other Arqade Meta styling issues](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/meta-background-flickers-on-some-monitors), there is a bug in the background between the footer and rest of the page that sometimes shows up when scrolling on Meta.  I *think* the body background is fixed but the footer's isn't, so sometimes you get a 2-pixel wide back stripe at the bottom of the page.  It's sensitive to browser height, as well as how you're scrolling (e.g. my mousewheel only seems to scroll an even number of pixels at a time)

[image: visible pixel seam]

This doesn't happen on the main site, as `#footer` has no background.

[Meta CSS](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gamingmeta/all.css?v=637368d500ba):

```
#footer {
    clear:both; color:#444; padding:0; 
    background:transparent url('img/bg-header.png') top center;
}
```

[Main CSS](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/all.css?v=637368d500ba):

```
#footer {
    clear:both; color:#444; padding:0;
}
```

Ignoring the footer's background style in Chrome eliminates the seam. For some reason there's a `bg-header.png`, which is 1-bit brighter than `bg-body.png` and repeated 61 times (it's 1x122 instead of 1x2)

Comment: I've got the same thing occasionally as well.  http://puu.sh/6je3n.png

Comment: Yep, I can repo in Pale Moon/Firefox.

Comment: Not seeing this in Safari.

Comment: @DavidM try scrolling with the scrollbar and/or changing the browser window height

Comment: Seeing those everywhere in the background, here and main site, on mobile chrome.

Comment: Still not seeing it in any browser window size.  And, OSX has largely done away with the scroll bar for the last three iterations.

Comment: I see it on Chrome, IE, and mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

I removed the meta footer bg image. The fix will go out after the next production build.